# How to fix applet working in eclipse but not in any browser

Tags: java, applet

I want to use java applet in dynamic web project but it's not working.
I created small applet:

```
`public class MyApplet extends JApplet {
    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextField textField;`

    /**
     * Create the applet.
     */
    public MyApplet() {
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblTag = new JLabel("Tag:");
        lblTag.setBounds(91, 51, 46, 14);
        getContentPane().add(lblTag);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(126, 48, 86, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

    }

}`
```

Then i putted it to .JAR file

Next i created Dynamic Web Project and allocate .JAR file in folder in which index.html file is.

I put also

```
`<applet code="MyApplet.class" archive="name.jar"   width="500" height="500" ></applet>`
```

to index.html file.

When i open this project on apache server i can see html file propertly with styles but aplet is not showing. It happend in every browser. I have not any error in console:

```
`sty 20, 2019 9:13:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.37
sty 20, 2019 9:13:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Dec 12 2018 12:07:02 UTC
sty 20, 2019 9:13:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.5.37.0
sty 20, 2019 9:13:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
sty 20, 2019 9:13:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
sty 20, 2019 9:13:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
sty 20, 2019 9:13:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121
sty 20, 2019 9:13:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_121-b13
sty 20, 2019 9:13:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
sty 20, 2019 9:13:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Admin\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
sty 20, 2019 9:13:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Projekty PWJJ\apache-tomcat-8.5.37\apache-tomcat-8.5.37
sty 20, 2019 9:13:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Admin\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
sty 20, 2019 9:13:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Projekty PWJJ\apache-tomcat-8.5.37\apache-tomcat-8.5.37
sty 20, 2019 9:13:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Admin\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
sty 20, 2019 9:13:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Projekty PWJJ\apache-tomcat-8.5.37\apache-tomcat-8.5.37\endorsed
sty 20, 2019 9:13:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1250
sty 20, 2019 9:13:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;;.]
sty 20, 2019 9:13:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
sty 20, 2019 9:13:47 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
sty 20, 2019 9:13:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
sty 20, 2019 9:13:47 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
sty 20, 2019 9:13:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 608 ms
sty 20, 2019 9:13:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
sty 20, 2019 9:13:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.37
sty 20, 2019 9:13:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
sty 20, 2019 9:13:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
sty 20, 2019 9:13:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 274 ms`
```

Comment: You don't.  Applets are outdated technologies and are not supported by any modern browser.

Comment: I agree with @JoeC -- applets have been dead for a number of years, and so is not something you should be pursuing now. Perhaps HTML/CSS/JavaScript is what you want.

Comment: Ok. Great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work with modern browsers. Java plugins allowing to run Applets are obsolete for quite some time now e.g. [Firefox did this in 2016](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2015/10/08/npapi-plugins-in-firefox/):

> Websites and publishers which currently use plugins such as Silverlight or Java should accelerate their transition to Web technologies. The Web platform is powerful and can usually do everything that a plugin can do. In the rare cases where a site needs to extend Web technologies, the recommended solution is to develop the additional features as a Firefox add-on. Site maintainers should prepare for plugins to stop working in all versions of Firefox by the end of 2016.